# How to extract a string from a bean returning string array in XML

Tags: java, xml, spring

I have a bean that returns a string array. I have another bean which requires a particular string.

Now that string is within the string array included in first bean. Is there any way I can reference that specific element only in XML without creating a new bean? There's no specific reason as to why I don't want to create a new bean, but I wanted to know if such a method exists.

In short, I am looking if I can do something like this in XML configuration:

```
...
<constructor-arg value="#{BeanThatReturnsAnArray[2]}"
...
```

Is it possible or do I have to create a new bean that returns a string?

Comment: What you you mean by _"bean that returns a string array"_?

Comment: For example if theres a bean called "x" that returns string array, i want to ref it and get a particular value from that array using xml (something like "x[2]")

Comment: You're repeating the same thing you included in your question. A bean *cannot* "return" anything, it can *have methods* that *return* something. Until you share a more accurate vision of your architecture your question is a bit unclear.